# got error on using pygccxml lib in python program for variable parsing

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, module

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parseVar.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pygccxml import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygccxml/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from . import declarations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygccxml/declarations/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .declaration import declaration_t
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygccxml/declarations/declaration.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import algorithms_cache
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygccxml/declarations/algorithms_cache.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .. import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygccxml/utils/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .utils import is_str
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygccxml/utils/utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "/home/jayesh/Desktop/random.py", line 10, in <module>
    print random.uniform(1.2, 2.5)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'uniform'
```

Can somebody please suggest how to fix this issue?

Comment: provide the code from your source files to help identify the problem for others

Comment: You've called your own script `random.py`. Rename it, you're masking the `random` module.

Comment: Got it thank you: roganjosh and Wladek Surala